# Create a Django REST API from a class diagram

Tags: python, django, rest, api, class-diagram

From the knowledge I have, one has two approaches: code first or database first.

There are frameworks where one defines the models and the relationships, and auto migrate creates the database in the mirror of what one has defined.

Tried to find something reverse, but appears to me that Django does what I mentioned first - if one created the class models and migrated, then Django would create the entity database model for us.

Considering I started with the database, I don't know anything automatic to do this or the best way to tackle it.

Comment: It's covered here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different ways to do that from the Class Diagram:

• Create the models and do the migration to create the DB.

• Create the DB and then integrate it just like you would do with a Legacy DB - [as it shows in Jon Clements comment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/legacy-databases) .